# nginx change phpmyadmin folder name change error

Tags: php, apache, configuration, nginx

i have my phpmyadmin setup as such

```
 location /phpmyadmin {
               root /usr/share/;
               index index.php index.html index.htm;
               location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                       try_files $uri =404;
                       root /usr/share/;
                       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                       fastcgi_index index.php;
                       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
               }
               location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                       root /usr/share/;
               }
        }
        location /phpMyAdmin {
               rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
        }
```

i am looking to change the folder name so that i can access phpmyadmin through /secure

```
 location /secure {
               root /usr/share/;
               index index.php index.html index.htm;
               location ~ ^/secure/(.+\.php)$ {
                       try_files $uri =404;
                       root /usr/share/;
                       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                       fastcgi_index index.php;
                       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
               }
               location ~* ^/secure/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                       root /usr/share/;
               }
        }
```

but it keeps giving me 404 not found , any help would be appretiated guys thanks

Comment: This config would look for /usr/share/secure on request.

Comment: then how should i change it mate ?

Comment: I never really tried. One easy (but not clean) possibility is to symlink /usr/share/secure to /usr/share/phpmyadmin - But there are much better solutions so I won't post this as answer. You may read the nginx docs.

Comment: could u post one of the better solutions mate

Answer (score 3):

The below works and tested

```
location /pma/ {
    alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
}

location ~ ^/pma/(.+\.php)$ {
    alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/$1;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;

    # From fastcgi_params
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
}
```

The key is to set the below

```
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
```

this is a variable that gets se in fastcgi_params but when to below it works like a charm
change the 'pma' in both places to anything to u want and it'll work...no need for sym link

cheers

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work.

```
location /secure/ {
    alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;

    location ~ ^/secure/(.+\.php)$ {
        alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/$1;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: keeps redirecting me to login page

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
location /secure {
    alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ ^/secure/(.+\.php)$ {
        alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/$1;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpmyadmin/$1;
        fastcgi_pass php;
    }

    location ~* ^/secure/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
        alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/$1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `alias` in this situation.

```
location /secure/ {
           alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
```

With above settings all the requests to `/secure/` will be dropped to `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/`.